# Average entries of lists of lists

Tags: python

I have a list of lists

```
my_list = [[8,2,3], [8,3,6], [2,3,9], [7,3,6], [2,6,4], [8,5,8]]
```

and would like to take the average of the last `n` entries of the list for each of its entries. To clarify, here is an example:

The average of the entries of the last 3 lists of `my_list` is:

```
[(7+2+8)/3, (3+6+5)/3, (6+4+8)/3] = [5.67, 4.67, 6]
```

I did it with a bunch of loops of loops but I feel like there is a way to do it in probably a line or two of code. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: use a slice to get the last N entries: `my_list[-n:]`

Answer (score 1):

use `np.mean` after you slice your list

```
import numpy as np

my_list = [[8,2,3], [8,3,6], [2,3,9], [7,3,6], [2,6,4], [8,5,8]]
n = 3

np.mean(my_list[-n:], axis=0) # -> array([5.66666667, 4.66666667, 6.        ])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a list comprehension and `zip`, with some help from `statistics.mean` to easily compute the mean:

```
my_list = [[8,2,3], [8,3,6], [2,3,9], [7,3,6], [2,6,4], [8,5,8]]
n = 3

from statistics import mean
[mean(x) for x in zip(*my_list[-n:])]

# OR using map
list(map(mean, zip(*my_list[-n:])))
```

output:

```
[5.666666666666667, 4.666666666666667, 6]
```